# scala kafka producer:Can't read Kafka version from MANIFEST.MF. Possible cause: java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-kafka

Part of build.sbt

```
scalaVersion := "2.11.0"

val sparkVersion = "2.1.1";

libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % sparkVersion % "provided";
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-sql" % sparkVersion % "provided";
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-streaming" % sparkVersion % "provided";

libraryDependencies += "com.datastax.spark" %% "spark-cassandra-connector" % "2.0.2";
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-streaming-kafka-0-8" % sparkVersion;
```

Producer code:

```
        updates.foreachPartition{ partition =>
            val kafkaProperties = new Properties();
            kafkaProperties.put("serializer.class","kafka.serializer.StringEncoder");
            kafkaProperties.put("metadata.broker.list",kafkaBrokers);
            //kafkaProperties.put("partitioner.class","RuleUpdateKafkaPartitioner");
            val kafkaConfig = new ProducerConfig(kafkaProperties);
            val kafkaProducer = new Producer[String,String](kafkaConfig);
            partition.foreach { record =>
                ...
                val data = new KeyedMessage[String,String](kafkaTopic,record.ruleID(),record_json.toString());
                kafkaProducer.send(data);
            }
            kafkaProducer.close();
```

Error:

> 17/06/16 17:52:05 INFO VerifiableProperties: Verifying properties
>   17/06/16 17:52:05 INFO VerifiableProperties: Property
>   metadata.broker.list is overridden to 10.1.29.186:9092 17/06/16
>   17:52:05 INFO VerifiableProperties: Property serializer.class is
>   overridden to kafka.serializer.StringEncoder
>   **17/06/16 17:52:05 WARN AppInfo$: Can't read Kafka version from MANIFEST.MF. Possible cause: java.lang.NullPointerException** 17/06/16
>   17:52:05 INFO VerifiableProperties: Verifying properties 17/06/16
>   17:52:05 INFO VerifiableProperties: Property metadata.broker.list is
>   overridden to 10.1.29.186:9092 17/06/16 17:52:05 INFO
>   VerifiableProperties: Property serializer.class is overridden to
>   kafka.serializer.StringEncoder 17/06/16 17:52:05 INFO
>   VerifiableProperties: Verifying properties 17/06/16 17:52:05 INFO
>   VerifiableProperties: Property metadata.broker.list is overridden to
>   10.1.29.186:9092 17/06/16 17:52:05 INFO VerifiableProperties: Property serializer.class is overridden to kafka.serializer.StringEncoder
>   17/06/16 17:52:05 INFO Producer: Shutting down producer

**UPDATE**
kafka is kafka_2.11-0.10.2.0

Comment: Based on code - https://github.com/apache/kafka/blob/0.8.2/core/src/main/scala/kafka/common/AppInfo.scala#L63, seems there's no proper `META-INF/MANIFEST.MF` in your jar. One thing you could check would be content of your jar file `jar tf ~/.m2/repository/org/apache/kafka/kafka-clients/0.10.2.1/kafka-clients-0.10.2.1.jar | grep "META-INF/MANIFEST.MF"`. It should have been put there by kafka build itself though

Comment: There might be fix for it in 0.10 - https://github.com/apache/kafka/pull/209

Answer (score 2):

This is a warning and your application won't crash because of it. The codes here are trying to load Kafka version from `MANIFEST.MF`. My hunch is you use a shaded jar and it doesn't include Kafka's `MANIFEST.MF`.

See https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KAFKA-1901 for more details.

Comment: Depends on which plugin you are using. But I think it's not worth to spend time figuring out how to add it.